# Python: How to write to data in a form of table to a spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel

I have a code that calculates a given function at different points, that is :

```
def f(x):
    return np.sin(x)
x=np.arange(-1,1,0.01)
print np.sin(x)
```

I want to store the values to an excel sheet using this format:

[image]

Is there a simple way to do it without using the pandas DataFrame since it this package is now working on my laptop

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do it is use the `csv` module to write to a csv file, which can then be read into excel.

An example would be:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

def f(val):
    return np.sin(val)

x = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.01)
y = f(x)

with open('outfile.csv', 'w') as fid:
    writer = csv.writer(fid)
    writer.writerow(['x'] + list(x))
    writer.writerow(['f(x)'] + list(y))
```

On the other hand, if you really want to write to excel, you can use packages that handle excel files. You can refer to http://www.python-excel.org/ for a list of relevant packages that are not `pandas`